# can't bind model on web api post

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I can't bind list of string to my model.

My model:

```
public class EditUserForm
{
    [BindProperty]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [BindProperty]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [BindProperty]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public List<string> ActualUserRoles { get; set; }

    public EditUserForm(IdentityUser user)
    {
        Id = user.Id;
        Username = user.UserName;
        Email = user.Email;
    }
    public EditUserForm()
    {
    }
}
```

In view I have connected with ActualUserRoles field html code as below:

```html
<div>
   <label for="user-actual-roles" class="control-label">Actual user roles:</label>
   <select asp-for="ActualUserRoles" multiple class="form-control text-center h-75" id="user-actual-roles">
   </select>
</div>
```

From jQuery AJAX I add dynamically (after page load) options to make it async.

But after I send form with it to controller like below:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Edit/{userId}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(string userId, EditUserForm editUserForm)
{
    //here editUserForm.ActualUserRoles is null, but anoter field like Email has proper value
    return View("some-view.cshtml", editUserForm);
}
```

I'm using ASP.NET Core 2.2.7

Comment: Try to use [FromBody] tag like below:
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(string userId, [FromBody]EditUserForm editUserForm)

Comment: multiple select list will return array of string not List of string. Try changing ActualUserRoles to array

Comment: @RafaqatAli This cause in my app 415 status code

Comment: @RajeshG this didn't help

Comment: Can you check if that field is having value in form data? you can verify this in network tab of developer tool

Comment: can you post your json which you are posting?